# changing projection in R without changing resolution

Tags: coordinate-system, r, resolution

I have the following code to re-project my raster data. My problem is that when I change the projection, it seems that the resolution as well as pixel values change. I want to maintain the original file resolution and values.

NOTE THAT: Since some pixels have high values (indicating non-vegetated areas), changing resolution causes somehow to resample the pixels and creating messy pixel values.

```
library(raster)

# Create RasterLayer object
r <- raster('C:/test/1.tif')

# Define spatial reference 
sr <- "+proj=utm +zone=16  +datum=WGS84 +units=m " 

# Project Raster
projected_raster <- projectRaster(r, crs = sr)

# Write the RasterLayer to disk 
writeRaster(projected_raster, filename="C:/test/5.tif")
```

Comment: What's the original coordinate reference system? Is it also in meters?

Comment: The original coordinate ref system is sinusoidal (hdf convertet to GeoTIFF from MODIS).

Comment: You really cant go from an orbital projection to a different projection in R, at least not reliably. There is a NASA software utility for this purpose.

Comment: we really need to see what your source raster looks like, and ideally get a copy of it or something of the same form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not using a reference raster you can use the `res` argument in the function to control the output resolution of the raster. Just make sure that you define the correct resampling method for your data. With integer (nominal) data you want `method="ngb"` (nearest neighbor) and with floating point (continuous) data you want `method="bilinear"`, which is the default. This is all detailed in the functions help, accessed using `?projectRaster`.

Comment: I used res argument as follow but I get error also: projected_raster <- projectRaster(r, crs = sr, res="463.62 463.62")
Error in (bb@xmax - bb@xmin)/xr : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: You just provide a single value for a square grid cell. If you want different sizes for the x,y dimensions the you provide two values in a c() statement. The values has to be consistent with the output projection, eg., can't define meters for a geographic projection.

Comment: Sorry that I am amateur, can you make an example regarding my case?

Comment: Instead of `res="463.62,463.62"` you do: `res=c(463.62,463.62)` - numbers, not a quoted string.

Comment: @Spacedman Still there is an issue, Let me give you an example, imagine two neighbor pixel one has the value of 32750 (as non vegetated area) and the other one has value of 150 which is in range of normal pixels. when reprojection happens, it seems some pixels are generated between these two pixels having the value between 32750 and 150 !

Comment: That's what `method="ngb"` fixes - it uses the nearest neighbour value, so it will *always* pick one of the values from the raster it is projecting, and *never* interpolate between values. Did you miss that from Jeffrey's answer?

Comment: Yes, I know, anything I can do if I don't want this fix? what if I mark 32750 as NA pixels?

Comment: If you change 32750s to NAs then you'll get some NAs in the output cells instead of 32750s. You can change the 32750s to NAs in the *output* raster for the same effect. What's the problem here? If you use `method="ngb"` then the value in the output cells is the category of the closest cell in the input raster after reprojection. What more do you want?

Comment: I don't want the image to be resample, I want it to just be projected according to a new ref system (From sinsusodial to WGS84)

Comment: @Seji, you really need to read up on the basics of GIS and spatial analysis. Resampling is a necessary part of reprojecting data. As mentioned in a previous comment, you need to use the NASA MRT utility to reproject from the MODIS sinsusodial project. You can download the utility from the LP DAAC site: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool We are trying to help you here but you need to listen! We would not be bringing up these issues if they were irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. my issue is when I use Gdalwarp in gdal using OSGeo4W shell, and reproject a TIFF file from sinusoidal to WGS84, the result is ok and it is different when I use R, and reproject the same image. see the comparison here [link](https://ibb.co/mdBf08). As you can see white pixels are NA, black are ok, but when I use R to reproject (left image), it creates some grey pixels that doesn't make sense, compared to gdal result (right image).